# How to save continious data values in a file with fstream in C++?

Tags: c++, real-time, fstream, ostream

I am doing real-time rendering and trying to save the `render_time` used per frame. So, it is continuous data until I close the viewport. In the rendering loop I am trying to do something like this:

```
    std::ofstream f;
    f.open("../data_file.dat");
    //f << "render time" << '\n';
    f << render_time << '\n'; 
    f.close();
```

I want to save all the frame's render time, but instead of that, only the last value before closing the viewport is saved in the `.dat` file.

```
// expected result
render time
0.02
0.06
0.01
...
```

```
// achieving result
0.01
```

I would appreciate it if someone suggests a solution that can add new values at the last row and keep previous values as well.

Comment: You should keep the file open and only close it when exiting your program. Or instead store the values in a buffer in memory and write them to disk when you are done.

Comment: Or instead use `std::ios::app` to append to the file

Comment: You should not be opening and closing the file for each frame rendered. That could take significantly more time than rendering the frame depending on your OS, settings and hardware.

Comment: Default behaviour of opening the file to write is to truncate, delete the contents and start over.

Comment: I just need to write the data, for example, if I run 60 frames, after closing the viewport, the data file should have 60 rows of rendering time. @drescherjm , are u suggesting `std::ofstream f{"../data_file.dat"};`?

Comment: I agree with the first post. Unless you are worried about your program crashing and losing data that is not written to disk.

Comment: Open the file in a wider scope. Don't open it in your rendering function or inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you @chrysante , now `std::ofstream f("../file.dat", std::ios::app); ... f.close();` is saving the data. What could be the better solution?

Comment: Remove the `f.close()` and move `std::ofstream f("../file.dat", std::ios::app);` to your `int  main()` and pass a reference to `f` to whatever function does the render. It's difficult to give more detailed information because we only see a small piece of the code and have to guess about the design of the rest of the program.

Comment: Could you write that as an answer that I can accept that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To always write to the end of a file, use `std::ios::app` to open the file:

```
std::fstream file("path/to/file", std::ios::app);
```

A better solution would be to store the values in a buffer in memory and then write that to disk once your program finished running:

```
// Initialization
std::vector<double> renderTimes;
// ...
// On every frame
renderTimes.push_back(render_time);
// ...
// On shut down
std::fstream file("../data_file.dat");
if (!file) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open file\n";
    return; // Skip the next section of code
}
// Store as human-readable text ...
for (double value: renderTimes) {
    file << value << "\n";
}
// ... or in binary format
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(renderTimes.data()), renderTimes.size() * sizeof(double));
```

This solution is superiour in most cases compared to writing directly to the file, because opening files has a considerable runtime overhead compared to simply writing a value to a location in memory. If your buffer grows too large to be easily kept in memory, you might have to write it to disk once in a while, but also that would not need to be done every frame.

Also worth mentioning as noted by @Jeremy Friesner is that this overhead is likely considerable enough to distort your measurements.

Comment: `std::vector` is that buffer memory?

Comment: You might want to mention *why* it's better to only write to disk at the end (i.e. because writing to disk during the measurement would likely affect the program's performance and thereby skew the measurements)